# PowerShell command for Add and Install .wsp to Site Collection

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-part, powershell, solution-package, solution

need to add and install ***.wsp*** file to the Site Collection using PoweShell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this below scripts from **SharePoint Management Shell**:

### For Farm solution

```
Add-SPSolution “Your WSP Location”\”Your WSP Name”.wsp

Install-SPSolution –Identity "WSP Name".wsp –WebApplication "Site Url" –GACDeployment
```

### For Sandbox solution

```
Add-SPUserSolution -LiteralPath c:\CandidateSandboxedSolutions\MySandboxedSolution.wsp -Site http://MyServer/sites/Contoso

Install-SPUserSolution -Identity MySandboxedSolution.wsp -Site http://MyServer/sites/Contoso
```

Hope this will help you!

**Reference:**

- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/5b1f04/add-and-deploy-solution-in-sharepoint-central-administration/
- http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2009/12/02/adding-and-deploying-solutions-with-powershell-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx
- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepointdeveloperdocs/2010/10/28/how-to-install-sandboxed-solution-with-powershell-sharepoint-management-shell/

Comment: Thanks!! This is for Web Application right? Is there anything for Site Collection?

Comment: WSP are installed at farm level. It gets deployed at web application level. You can activate - deactivate features in the different site collections as per your requirements.

Comment: if you want to deploy the solutions specifically to site collections you need to build sandbox solutions.